# Как определить каких значений больше всего в таблице?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в ней есть ячейка `name`, значение в ней не уникальное и может повторяться.

Как определить каких `name` в таблице больше всего?

Comment: Посчитать. Отсортировать по убыванию. Взять первое.

Comment: На будущее, все операции с подсчетом полей производятся прямо в базе данных. Поэтому РНР к таким вопросам не имеет отношения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сгруппируйте результаты по нужному полю, и посчитайте, используя `count`.
Затем отсортируйте в нужном порядке.

Если вам нужны все записи, то код будет примерно таким:

```sql
select
    t.name,
    count(*)
from some_table t
group by t.name
order by 2 desc
```

Если же нужна только одна запись с наибольшим количеством повторений, то можете лимитировать результат:

```sql
select
    t.name,
    count(*)
from some_table t
group by t.name
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

Если принять в расчёт справедливый комментарий от @Akina о том, что может быть несколько `name` с одинаковыми `count`, то можно выполнить запрос предложенный им в комментарии ниже либо запрос такого вида:

```sql
select
    q.name,
    q.count
from (
    select
        t.name,
        count(*) as count,
        rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rank
    from some_table t
    group by t.name
) q
where q.rank = 1
```

Comment: `limit` не нужен

Comment: А если два имени одинаково самые частые (количество равно)? Выведется только одно, причём фиг знает какие из них.

Comment: да, второй вариант (который теперь первый) верный, сам я не правильно прочитал вопрос

Comment: @Akina взяв за основу ваш вариант, добавил третий блок кода, решающий обозначенную вами проблему

Comment: Осталось убедиться, что у автора версия сервера знает про оконные функции... :)

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT name, COUNT(name) cnt FROM table GROUP BY name),
cte2 AS (SELECT name, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk FROM cte1)
SELECT name FROM cte2 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Будут выведены только имена - одно или, если максимальное количество совпадает, несколько. Если нужно ещё и количество, добавить поле `cnt` в список вывода `cte2` и основного запроса.

Comment: Для пятой версии - то же реализовать подзапросами и эмулировать `RANK()` (например, используя UDV).

Comment: а теперь сделайте explain - `Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: @Gedweb Ну так задача такая... я даже теоретически не представляю индекс, который позволит сортировать по COUNT(field)...